# TypeError when overriding assertEqual in derived class

Tags: python, unit-testing

I override `unittest.TestCase` with my own class where I want to add some extra functionality to `assertEqual`:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):        
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        unittest.TestCase.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def _write_to_log(self):
        print "writing to log..."

    def assertEqual(self, first, second, msg=None):
        self._write_to_log()
        unittest.TestCase.assertEqual(first, second, msg)
```

But I am getting `TypeError: unbound method assertEqual() must be called with TestCase instance as first argument (got int instance instead)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `assertEqual` as a class method, without passing an instance: this is why Python complains that the method is *unbound*.

You should probably use:

```
super(MyTestCase, self).assertEqual(first, second, msg)
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to pass in `self` to `assertEqual`:

```
unittest.TestCase.assertEqual(self, first, second, msg)
```

You should really use `super()` throughout your overrides:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):        
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(MyTestCase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def assertEqual(self, first, second, msg=None):
        self._write_to_log()
        super(MyTestCase, self).assertEqual(first, second, msg)
```